# Sitemap with alternate langs urls, but same images

Tags: seo, xml-sitemap

I'm trying generate the xml sitemap for a ecommerce website. Is a multilanguage project and the product pages are in multiple languages, but same product images are the same. Reading [Google post for multilang sitemaps](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2012/05/multilingual-and-multinational-site.html) and [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2620865?hl=en) it seems that I must do this:

```
<url>
  <loc>http://www.example.com/en/product-1</loc>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://www.example.com/de/product-1" />
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.example.com/en/product-1" />
  <image:image>
   <image:loc>http://www.example.com/image1.jpg</image:loc>
  </image:image>
  <image:image>
   <image:loc>http://www.example.com/image2.jpg</image:loc>
  </image:image>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.example.com/de/product-1</loc>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://www.example.com/de/product-1" />
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.example.com/en/product-1" />
  <image:image>
   <image:loc>http://www.example.com/image1.jpg</image:loc>
  </image:image>
  <image:image>
   <image:loc>http://www.example.com/image2.jpg</image:loc>
  </image:image>
```

**So my question is, I must repeat images in all urls if they are always the same??**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If an image is surrounded by German text, it will rank in German. Same for other languages.

If your pages point to those images, Google will find them and rank them properly. So the answer to your question would be no.